# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'dispatch' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am using React Redux. Getting error - Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'dispatch' of undefined

Below is what console shows

[image]

I know I am really close because it worked briefly and I added some code that messed it up. I was seeing the payload for GET_RESULTS but now I do not because of this error.

This is what I call when **submit** button on search form is clicked. I get data from the API and that part works fine.

```
.....
import { store } from '../../../store/store'
import { getSearchResults } from '../../../actions/searchresults'
....
...
   handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    get(`apiURLHere`, { maxContentLength: 400 })
    .then((data) => store.dispatch(getSearchResults(data)))
  }
```

Here is my **action** -

```
export const getSearchResults = username => {
  return {
    type: 'GET_RESULTS',
    payload: username,
  }
}
```

Comment: Why are you logging after a return?

Comment: The log was just to see if I am getting into the Action.js. I can remove that as its not relevant code. Thanks

Comment: I removed the console.log and now get the same error - TypeError: Cannot read property 'dispatch' of undefined

Comment: @StaeAzure If you're using React Redux, you can use dispatch as a prop. e.g. ```this.props.dispatch(getSearchResults(data));``` Make sure you bind handleSubmit to `this` component in your constructor.. `this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);`

Comment: Thanks. Yes, Im using React. I updated the code as I saw this in docs too but get same error. Please see update above in question which has my new code.

Comment: To use `this.props.dispatch` you have to use [connect](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options) method of `react-redux`. For example: `export default connect()(YourComponent)`. Then in `YourComponent` you can use `this.props.dispatch`.

Comment: You're probably importing `store` wrong. You should be using React Redux.

Comment: @Max Thanks - I have these lines in my main App.js.. `import { connect } from 'react-redux' .. ` ..... `export default connect(mapStateToProps)(App)`.. It was working earlier this morning. I added some logic and I started seeing this error. Just cant figure out what.

Comment: Could you add complete code of this component?

Comment: @kiarashws - Sure -Added complete code under Update - Adding complete code. I added main App.js code as well to show connect and react-redux is used but I had this working without modifying App.js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In  **search-advanced.js** file,  you should import connect instead of importing store,  then connect your component and dispatch would be in props of component:

```
import { store } from '../../../store/store' // remove this line
import {connect}  from 'react-redux'
```

Change:

```
export default class SearchAdvanced extends Component
```

To

```
class SearchAdvanced extends Component
```

And instead of `store.dispatch` use:

```
this.props.dispatch(getSearchResults(searchResults))
```

And at the end of file add:

```
export default connect()(SearchAdvanced)
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks so much for that.